# I just can't seem to make grid fill work for me

Tags: mesh, objects, vertices

I'm not sure why I just can't seem to make grid fill work for me.

I have an equal amount of vertices to fulfill the action of applying it yet it turns into this jumbled mess.

I really don't know how to fix this and I've redone this mesh at least 10 times now trying to figure out why but I've had zero luck. If someone could help me with this I'd appreciate it so much!

[image]

Comment: It's got late here now, so I can't answer this fully until tomorrow, but it looks as if you swept  the _front_  of the profile round the path, and then filled in the back, _after_ converting to a mesh, instead of sweeping a whole,closed, curve-loop? So you don't have enough vertices in the flat back of the profile. You could cut a few loops in there now, to get  a more even density of verts around the profile, not forgetting to wind up with an even number.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hi! Well, I used did the profile curve like how you had explained in my last post (how I shaped https://i.imgur.com/vkcooLx.png), but I did notice that the back doesn't have any vertices going across it (https://i.imgur.com/0KIN0UC.png). Maybe I am just confusing myself more but I'm not sure how to fix what I should be doing. On one of my meshes I tried I did get the vertices to cross in the back however the front was still weird (here https://i.imgur.com/5O8pQmi.png) and my seat didn't come out well. Sorry, I'm quite slow with learning.

Comment: grid fill will not create new vertices, they have to exist already. Probably you need an equal amount of loop cuts on the back to have a regularly spaced grid to fill. Also keep in mind that grid fill has different setting for you to get different kind of arrangements using span and offset. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html?highlight=grid%20fill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill* works like this:

[image]

- It calls the (white) active vertex when it is invoked a "corner". (Red zones)
- It takes the next `Span - 1` vertices, and bridges them to their opposite numbers. (Lilac)
- It skips another corner, and then connects what's left cross-ways. (Green).

This results in `Span` face-loops across the piece, (up, in the picture :) ) and 4 corners.

The illustration shows `Spans` of `4,3,2` and `1` on a 16-circle, with the active vertex in white.

(The `Offset` setting steps the starting-point around the perimeter.)

So you can see, to get a tidy result from *Grid Fill*, you need:

- An even number of vertices
- A reasonably nice correspondence of vertices to their opposite numbers, once you've decided where the first corner should go.

In your case, you need to fix the second condition.